# Adding a CSS class to all products in a particular category using a function in WooCommerce

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

how would I go about adding a CSS class to all products in a particular category using a function?

```php
function DW_remove_add_to_cart_buttons() {
    if ( is_product() && !has_term ( 'product-has-vendor', 'product_cat' ) ) {
       add CSS class 'my-custom-css-class'
    }
}
```

---

So in the above code: If viewing a product page, not in the category 'product-has-vendor', add CSS class.

How do I achieve this please?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/programmatically-adding-a-class-to-products/

Comment: So use add_filter('wc_product_post_class....?

Comment: Just give it a try

Comment: Yes I did, and no change. It didn't add the classes...

Comment: wc_product_post_class only works on single product not in the loop.